# Алгоритм работы поискового паука

Tags: веб-программирование, алгоритм, search

Составил список действий по порядку поискового паука
Если я что то пропустил, помогите, дополните.
Если что то поисковой робот на PHP (знаю, знаю это глупо, но я так хочу)

1. Получил URL сайта из DB (в моём случае MYSQL).
2. Перешел по URL (при помощи File get contents не извращение?).
3. Проверил на странице meta ну что индексировать можно, а что нет.
4. Получил кодировку.
5. Получил Title.
6. Получил keywords.
7. Получил description.
8. Затем получил все ссылки (удалил те ссылки которые равны URL индексируемой страницы), занес их в DB в список  URL для индексации.
9. Удалил все теги.
10. Занёс в DB title, кодировку, ключевые слова(если есть), описание(если есть) и текст со страницы.
11. Элемент списка

Comment: Удаляйте из обработки внешние ссылки, их помещайте в базу данных с сайтами.

Comment: Ещё не забудьте пропустить все ссылки, по которым страницы уже загружались ранее

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше разделить на индексатора и обработчика.

```
1. Индексатор должен только переходить по ссылками из базы и сохранять новые страницы в нее.
2. Обработчик, в паралельном процессе, парсить все данные, титлы и т.д. сохраненной страницы.
```

Это позволить ускорить индексацию, и наращивать мощьность парсера не в ущерб индексатору.

Answer (score 2):

Поисковый паук состоит из двух частей:

1. Spider - именно паук, который перебирает все ссылки на сайте **"удалил те ссылки    которые равны URL индексируемой страницы), занес их в DB в список URL для индексации"**.
   И удалил ссылки на другие сайты, оставив только внутренние.
2. Scrapper - "скребок", который переходит по ссылкам из БД, соскребает нужные дынные и после добавляет к ссылке данные типа "Done" и дату напр.

Считаю, что данные процессы не обязательно должны быть параллельными, можно их запустить последовательно. Сначала вы соберете базу всех страниц, а после этого вытяните с них данные.